# Regex expression not to match line

Tags: regex, line

I'd like to ask how to make a regex expression, which will select all the lines which does not contain this pattern: `(.*:.*)`

I tried it like this

```
^((?!(.*:.*)).)*$
```

from [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html) but I can't get it work.

Comment: It's worth noting that grep has a flag `-v` which inverts the results i.e. shows all lines which do not match the pattern passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this it looks to me like you're trying to select all the lines that don't contain a `:`.

To this end you could use the following regex:

`^([^:]+)$`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd like to ask, is it possible to remove all the lines with colon from the start, but just until the three lines without colon appear? Now I have regex which matches lines with colon and lines without it but can't make it together.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do something like that with Regex. That operation is better suited for whatever language you're using. At that point, it would probably be easier just to read each line, determine if it has a `:`, and act accordingly. Once you get into more complex find/replace/remove operations, Regex becomes less useful and more complex to use, so it's often suggested to just use whatever parent language you're coding in to get the job done, since it'll typically be more efficient and easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this pattern, and set options `g` for global and `m` for multiline:

```
^([^:]*)$
```

Change the `*` to a `+` if you don't want to capture empty lines (you didn't specify).

Fiddle: http://www.rexfiddle.net/pmEFFQR

Answer (score 2):

I believe (.*:.*) means, 0 or more of any character, followed ':', followed by 0 or more of any character. so the following would match that.

- a:b
- abc:def
- :abc
- abc:
- :

basically, if we break this down, we are looking for any line that does not contain the ':' character. so something like this would work

```
^[^:]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex :

```
^(?!(.*:.*)).*(\n|$)
```

`?!(.*:.*)` is a negative look-ahead to ensure there is no pattern matching `.*:.*` ahead.

Such a line with zero or more characters are matched by the following `.*` and it has to be followed by new line (\n) or end of string ($).

Comment: I missed the new line